# Conversion constructor clarification

Tags: c++, constructor, assignment-operator

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test 
{
 private:
   int x;
 public:
    Test(int i) 
    {
        cout<<"Conversion constructor called..."<<endl;
        x = i;
    }
    ~Test()
    {
        cout<<"Destructor called..."<<endl;
    }
    void show() 
    { 
        cout<<" x = "<<x<<endl; 
    }
};

int main()
{
  Test t(20);
  t.show();
  t = 30; 
  t.show();

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Conversion constructor called...
 x = 20
Conversion constructor called...
Destructor called...
 x = 30
Destructor called...
```

When i am doing t = 30 why it is calling constructor and destructor?
Please explain.Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no overload of `=` that can be used to assign directly from an `int` value. Your conversion constructor allows `30` to be converted to a `Test` object, which can then be assigned using the implicitly-generated copy constructor (which copies each member). So your assignment is equivalent to

```
t = Test(30);
```

creating and destroying a temporary object to assign from.

You could avoid this by providing an assignment operator:

```
Test & operator=(int i) {x = i;}
```

in which case the assignment could use this directly, equivalent to

```
t.operator=(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `t = 30`, your compiler creates a temporary `Test` variable, which it creates using the conversion constructor. After setting `t` equal to this temporary variable, the temporary variable is then destroyed, calling the destructor.

Comment: @paddy: The default assignment operator is for copy-assignment from another `Test`, not from arbitrary types.

Answer (score 1):

Because `t` is already defined, it cannot be initialized throug the convertion contructor.

Instead, it creates a temporay `Test` object, calls the operator=, then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

> *"why it is calling constructor and destructor?"*

Because there's a (implicit) temporary instance of `Test` constructed, assigned to `t` and destructed after assignment.